# Not getting right output in java deletion program

Tags: java

when i compile run my java deletion program it removes the number from given input but it paste the after it two times.

```
import java.util.*;
class deletion
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int a[],i,k;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total number of Inputs");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        a = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter Your Inputs");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }
       System.out.println("Enter the number index you want to delete");
       k = sc.nextInt();
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           if(a[i] == k)
           {
               a[i] = a[i+1];

           }
       }
    System.out.println("Deleted Successfully.....!");
       System.out.println("Output:");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           System.out.println(a[i]);
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Java arrays are fixed length. There is no way to delete an element without creating a new array. Also, you want to remove the element at index `k`. Not an array element that has `k` as the value.

Comment: Use a list instead of an array